# is it compatible library compiled with g++/libstdc++ and client compiled with (clang/g++/gcc)/libstdc++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, libstdc++

I am not expert linux family compiler.

I wonder the static library built with g++/libstdc++ can be used some compiler (clang/g++/gcc) and linked with libstdc++ (as long as I know, the libstdc++ and libc++ is not compatible. so I restrict them to libstdc++)

It is important to library development, to allows whatever user used, can be supported.

and also,

compiled with c++98 / gnu c++98 can be used library - and client structure? 
how about c++98 / c++11, respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the libraries will be compatible if you use the same binutils and not use some conflicting compiler flags. The compatibility also doesn't depend on the C standard.